# why my application crash when we have 64 java installed alone

Tags: java, performance, jvm-hotspot, jvm-arguments, jvm-crash

There are two scenario's

Scenario 1: In windows 7 or 10, When I have two java installed (1.8u202 32 bit and 1.8u202 64 bit). My application(Swing application) was launched with 64 bit java and is running fine for months.

Scenario 2:  In windows 7 or 10, When I have only 1.8u202 64 bit java installed .My application(Swing application) was launched with 64 bit java crashes after 2 days of running. Reason of crash is Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate bytes for ChunkPool::allocate.

The Java argument are same in the both the scenario.

Ideally when the application is launched using the 64 bit java  even though you have both 32 and 64 bit java installed should behave same like application launched using the 64 bit java when you have 64 bit java installed.

**Why crash is only happening when you have 64 bit java installed only .**

Is there any difference in memory model or memory referencing when you have both 32 and 64 bit java installed .

Comment: Crash report.
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate bytes for ChunkPool::allocate
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   The process is running with CompressedOops enabled, and the Java Heap may be blocking the growth of the native heap

Current thread (0x0000000016202000):  JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6240, stack(0x0000000017860000,0x0000000017960000)]

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the crash report in the body of the question(with appropriate formatting).

Comment: Coincidence doesn't imply causality. How many times did you install and uninstall the 32 bit version, to be so confident that the absence of it causes the crash of the other installation?